# appengine datastore change entities property

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, jodatime

I would like to change the entity property from String to long. I have seen Nick answering similar problem in [Change IntegerProperty to FloatProperty of existing AppEngine DataStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742875/change-integerproperty-to-floatproperty-of-existing-appengine-datastore) but I am writing in Java and need some code example since I don't know anything about the mapreduce.

e.g. we want to change userId from String to Long of [this class](http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-AppEngine/src/com/cloudtasks/server/Task.java).

I also would like to get advice on my thinking of storing date in long instead of String so that the time information can be consumed readily from android, GWT and more(over Rest Json or RPC). Right now, GWT does not have Jodatime and it has limited support of Java.util.Date and parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to convert from String to Long, I can't see any other choice except to write a conversion snippet using raw GAE, eg:

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQuery;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;

Query q = new Query (Task.class.getName());
PreparedQuery pq = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService ().prepare (q);
for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable ())
{
    String orig = entity.getProperty ("userId").toString ();
    entity.removeProperty ("userId");
    entity.setProperty ("userId", Long.parseLong (orig));
}
```

Comment: The code is not getting into for loop though I have quite a few of the data entries.

Comment: "MyKind" is a String, and it is case sensitive.

Comment: I have updated the question (and also your code snippet, it has not been peer reviewed yet.) to use Task.java as an example.So, in place of "MyKind", I have used Task.class.getName() but it skips the for loop.

Comment: The arguments for Query constructor should be the same what you'd run from within the Datastore Viewer using GQL in the Dashboard, eg: `SELECT * FROM Task`. The argument is case sensitive.

Comment: hmmm... I tried a couple of variation `"select from " + Task.class.getName() + " where userId!=null"` , `"SELECT * FROM Task WHERE userId!=null"` and since Query already seems to include "SELECT * FROM", I just try `"Task WHERE userId!=null"` it still is not working.

Comment: I do the null checking in java(updated) and it goes through the for loop, yet it remains string in data store when I look through the console. I don't see any new Long entry also.

Comment: Make sure you're not using Transactions - or if you are, commit each time within the looop.

Comment: I am not using any transaction but just the code snippet in the answer. I added `DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().put(entity);` in loop but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

What is your persistence interface? JDO (mine), JPA, Objectify, Twig, raw GAE/J API? I don't think that many people can give you a code example without knowing this.

Also, please give the code extract of your existing (an underlying date-time, I presume) persistent entity including the data member you talk about.

Comment: Sorry about that. I come from developing for android and don't know much about that. I believe that it is JDO. I have iterated my code from google IO demo project. http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-AppEngine/src/com/cloudtasks/server/Task.java About the date-time, I store it as a String and parse it before I manipulate it for further usage. It is not to display to human but to calculate for end time. Thus, I wonder if it is a good idea to store it as a long to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is using JPA not JDO. The latest version (v2.x) of the GAE JPA plugin allows persistence of (java.util.)Date as Long or String. This wouldn't cater for your migration of data (see the reply by Jonathan for that) but would allow you to persist future Date fields as Long. IIRC you can specify the "jdbcType" (DataNucleus extension annotation) as INTEGER would trigger that.

Comment: actually, I think, it is JDO. In my project, I find this config file war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/jdoconfig.xml I am using the latest google GAE plugin Can you advice me why Jonathan's advice is not working? The code went through the loop but the data store never change. I tried to save the entity like this `DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().put(entity);` but it still is not working.

Comment: So why do you have @Entity etc all over the classes? Where is the persistence code? pm.makePersistent? em.persist?

Comment: it seems that google use @Entity whether it is JPA or JDO https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory I do pm.makePersistent.

Comment: hmm... it's working on the local GAE dev server. The only changes I recall is the google plugin updates.